# Is Quorum production ready

Tags: blockchain, consensus, quorum, proof-of-authority

Quorum is private permissioned blockchain network.Is it production ready or still in beta/Proof of Concept stage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, JPMorgan's Quorum is ready to use with quite guarantees (which doesn't mean that it couldn't be improved or stuff like that).

**Think about that, Quorum isn't more than the [Raft Consensus Algorithm](https://raft.github.io/)** but hoarding control about some Byzantinism, **not all of them because on a private/permisioned blockchain, you can asume that not all of the typical byzantine behaviors are possible to realize.**

- **To sumarize a lot, Quorum is a PoA blockchain that takes care about some concret byzantine behaviours.**
- **And raft has been used for years and is more than tested.**

Another similar example of this are Istanbul Consensus Blockchains.

- Also add that for example, [Alastria](https://alastria.io/#1), runned since a few months ago with JPMorgan's Quorum, so obviously, isn't in a Concept Stage, which doesn't mean that it can't change somethings with the pass of the time.

Hope it helps.